# How many different words of length 24 , made of 7a , 8b, 5c and 4d that do not contain "ac" neither "ca" are outhere?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different words of length 24 , made of 7a , 8b, 5c and 4d that do not contain "ac" neither "ca" are outhere?

So , I am thinking of it like this : Without any limitation , we can create $\frac{24!}{7!8!5!4!}$ different words .  I am going to calculate in how many there is at least one of "ca" or "ac" . Assume we put at least  a "ca" or ac" , there are 2 ways to do this  . We are left with 22 positions and 6a , 8b, 4c, 4d so we can have $\frac{22!}{6!8!4!4!}$ different permutations with those 22 letters. Now , we can put our "ac" or "ca" in 21 + 2 = 23 different positions , so we 23 choices.
Hence , there are $\frac{24!}{7!8!5!4!}$ - $\frac{22!}{6!8!4!4!}* 2* 23$ words that do not contain "ca" or "ac" . Feedback? Alternatives?

> There is a simpler problem which asks only to not contain ' ca'And here comes my teacher solution:
> We can arrange 7a,8b and 4d with $\frac{19!}{8!4!7!}$ different ways .
> Now we need to add those 5c's. There are 13 legal positions for 'c's (before a 'b' , before a 'd' or in the end) . Hence , we can put those 5c's in 13 positions . And there are $C(13+5-1,5)=\frac{17!}{5!12!}$ ways to do this. Final answer: $\frac{19!}{8!4!7!}$ $*$ $\frac{17!}{5!12!}$

Comment: You can’t choose any two positions to put an “ac” or a “ca”; the positions need to be adjacent.

Comment: so if i miss the c(24,2) is that ok?

Comment: Also, when counting words that violate the constraint, if for each pair of adjacent positions you put an “ac” or “ca” there, then count the number of possible words letting the other positions be any of the remaining letters, then you’ll over count the violations, because some of those other positions may be “ac” or “ca”.

Comment: @Joe we do not overcount those other positions that may hold "ac" or "ca" because those "ac" and "ca" where made off the reamining 4c and 6a , not from the a and c we put in the first place. Do you agree?

Comment: The problem with that approach is that when you put “ac” in the first two slots, one of the faulty words you’ll count will also have “ac” in, for example, slots 3 & 4, but then, when you choose slots 3 & 4 to put your violating “ac”, one of the faulty words you’ll form will be the same word you counted earlier with “ac” in the first two slots.

Comment: If you don’t agree with me, imagine you have just 2a, 1b, and 2c to form 5 letter words, and count how many have “ac” or “ca” using that technique.

Comment: brucebanner, you are obviously overcounting positions with more than one ca or ac in them. @Joe has explained this very well. If you don't see it, then please think about it for a while, until you do. (By the way, this problem looks difficult to me.)

Comment: i changed my solution , any feedback now?

Comment: I don't understand your teacher's solution, but it looks incorrect. It seems like your teacher is saying that once you arrange the 7a/8b/4d, which is 19 letters, that the c's can go (ignoring the constraint) in any of the 20 positions that are in between any two of those letters, or on the end. But you cannot just choose 5 of those 20 positions for the 5c, because all 5c could go together at the beginning.  Also, there are not necessarily 2*7 illegal positions, because all 7a could be at the beginning, so the position after an 'a' could be the same as the position before a different 'a'.

Comment: I also don't understand how your teacher says that 14 illegal positions out of 20 available positions means that we can put the 5c in 13 positions. Your solution still has the over-counting I described above. I agree with @TonyK, this seems like a difficult problem. I am not sure the right way to solve it.  I'd personally use Python and do an exhaustive search, but I'm sure that's not what your teacher wants you to do.

Answer (score 3):

1. Replace 8b  and 4d with 12e, and multiply the final result by $12\choose4$.
2. Suppose the 7a form $p$ groups, and the 5c form $q$ groups.  Breaking them up can be done in ${6\choose p-1}{4\choose q-1}$ ways, and alternating them in $p+q\choose p$ ways.
3. The $p+q$ blocks can be strewn among the 12e in $13\choose p+q$ ways.
4. I think it is $${12\choose4}\sum_{p=1}^7\sum_{q=1}^5{6\choose p-1}{4\choose q-1}{13\choose p+q}{p+q\choose p}$$

Comment: This seems like a good direction, but what do you mean by "breaking them up can be done in ... ways"? I count that for $q=3$ there are only 2 ways to form 3 groups [not C(4,3)]: c, c, ccc; or c, cc, cc.  Then, when counting how many ways those groups can be "strewn among the 12e", how do you account for the fact that some of those groups may be identical, while others may not be?

Comment: I am counting c,c,ccc different from c,ccc,c, so I get ${4\choose3-1}=6$ ways.  Then I don't shuffle them later

Comment: Impressive answer

Comment: This evaluates to $24,222,137,940$ and the total is confirmed via code.

Comment: @brucebanner, this is the correct answer, so you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I computed the same value for @Empy's answer as @Daniel Mathias, which I also confirmed with code: 24,222,137,940.

I rewrote my function to be more general. It still finishes in under 0.1 seconds. It gives the same value as the teacher for the teacher's problem (as opposed to the originally posted problem) in which the word cannot contain "ca" (but can contain "ac"), which is 154,341,467,280.

I was surprised it matches. I still don't understand the teacher's solution. I don't understand where the 17 choose 5 comes from.

```
from scipy.special import comb
from math import factorial as fact
from datetime import datetime
import time

# Save answers to file
myfile = open('myLog' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') + '.txt', 'a')

# compute count from analytic solution
count = 0
for p in range(7):
    for q in range(5):
        count += (comb(6, p, exact=True)
                  *comb(4, q, exact=True)
                  *comb(13, p+q+2, exact=True)
                  *comb(p+q+2, p+1, exact=True)
                  )
count = comb(12, 4, exact=True)*count

print ("Count for OP's question from analytic solution = ",
       count, '\n', file=myfile)

# A function to count the words
def countWords(letters, counts, constraints, after=None, memo=None):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    letters : a string of unique letters, e.g. "abcd"
    counts : a tuple representing the counts of those leters, e.g. (1,2,3,4)
    constraints : a tuple of ORDERED PAIRS of letters that cannot appear in
                  the word, e.g. ("ac", "ca")
    after : Leave empty. For recursive calls ONLY. Last letter before call.
    memo : Leave empty. For recursive calls ONLY. Solved sub-problems.

    Returns
    -------
    result : the number of words that can be formed from all of the letters,
             while satisfying the constraints.
    """
    if memo==None: # on the first call of countWords
        memo={}
    if (counts,after) in memo: # if sub-problem already solved
        return memo[(counts,after)]
    if after == None:
        after = "7" # make any character not in letters
    result = 0
    if sum(counts)==1: # only one letter left
        if ((after + [letters[i] for i,v in enumerate(counts) if v > 0][0])
            not in constraints):
            result = 1 # if it doesn't violate the constraint, add the word
    else: # make recursive calls:
        for i in range(len(letters)):
            if counts[i]>0 and ((after+letters[i]) not in constraints):
                currentCount = list(counts) # convert count to list
                currentCount[i] = counts[i]-1 # to decrement this letter
                result += countWords(letters,
                                     tuple(currentCount),
                                     constraints,
                                     after=letters[i],
                                     memo=memo)
    memo[(counts,after)] = result # save answer to sub-problem
    return result

# Time how long it takes to find the solution
myStart = time.time()

# original question asked by OP
functionCount = countWords(letters="abcd",
                           counts=(7, 8, 5, 4),
                           constraints=("ac", "ca"))
print("Count for OP's question from function = ",
      functionCount, file=myfile)

# Stop timer
myStop = time.time()
print("Elapsed time for OP's question = ", myStop - myStart, '\n', file=myfile)

# original question asked by OP
functionCount = countWords(letters="abcd",
                           counts=(7, 8, 5, 4),
                           constraints=("ca"))
print("Count for teacher's question from function = ",
      functionCount, file=myfile)

# The count according to the teachers solution
teachersCount = (
    (fact(19)/(fact(8)*fact(4)*fact(7)))
    *(fact(17)/(fact(5)*fact(12)))
    )
print("Count for teacher's questions according to teacher's solution = ",
      teachersCount, '\n', file=myfile)

myfile.close()
```

With output:

```
Count for OP's question from analytic solution =  24222137940 

Count for OP's question from function =  24222137940
Elapsed time for OP's question =  0.06250238418579102 

Count for teacher's question from function =  154341467280
Count for teacher's questions according to teacher's solution =  154341467280.0
```

Comment: the truth is that i misunderstood what my teacher said , his solution was to the problem : strings that do not contain "ca'' ( or ac , but not both constrained). He is a valuable professor and I have to admit that I truly believe he "checks twice" before he gives us something. But the problem with both constraints , may actually be hard as it seems.

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that @Empy2 correctly answered the question that YOU asked.

Comment: of course , never doubted that. just felt the need to clarify that it was my mistake , not my teacher's one

Comment: Then why haven't you accepted his answer yet?