# What's the number of arrangements of all 7 letters of the word "MINIMUM" in which the letters M are separated?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I came across a question in a exerise booklet for Mathematical Olympiad for year 6 primary school students in Australia. The questions is as follows:

Find the number of arrangements of all 7 letters of the word "MINIMUM" in which the letters M are separated.

I calculated the number of arrangements as 360, but the provided keys says it's 720 instead. I'm not sure whether the key is right because the totoal number of arrangements when there are no restrictions is 420. I don't know why the key is 720. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The correct answer is [$120$](https://tio.run/##RcshEsNACABAf6/AASampl@IoC4PqLhM6STAcET09depqt@NT73cbvfIOfUMzwKtnuV@jBapVtSObjR6kcLuCQpqf7NEz/OqZ6nbIJT1scomyKA7oAiCef0C4vJ2NVJmbjznFw). Maybe they considered all the $M$s different?)

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeyBurdin. Would you please give hints as to how 120 was calculated? Thanks again.

Comment: I agreee with @AlexeyBurdin. But if the $M$s and the $I$s are all different it would be $120 \times3!\times2!=1440$

Comment: @MichaelMay straightforward -- counting all the permutations of `MINIMUM` not containing `MM` and eliminating duplicates. $7!$ operations is not that much for a computer)

Comment: Alternatively, count the number of ways you can locate the $M$s. Then there are 4 places to put the $U$ and 3 places to put the $N$. The $I$s must go into the remaining spots.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeyBurdin for your solutions and explanations. I'm beginning to have an idea of how to think about the matter. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you, @Peter, for your alternative way of looking at the problem. It's really a mind opener. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The title says the M's are separated; the question text just says "the letters are separated." Please clarify!

Comment: The title must be right. How could “the letters” be separated?

Comment: @Joe It can for example mean "the identical letters" (as was suggested in the given answer).

Comment: But that would be assuming that the body is wrong AND the title is wrong, and that he not only forgot the word identical in the body, he also forget it in the title AND accidentally wrote an “M”.

Comment: @Joe: I am sure you are right. But the question still needs editing.

Comment: Yes, Michael, please edit your question.

Comment: My thanks for all. The question has been since revised. My apology.

Comment: Thank you, @TonyK, for pointing out the mistake in the body of my question. The condition should have been "the letters M are separated". That makes things clearer.

Comment: Thank you, @Joe for participating in the clarification of the matter. I'm sorry to have confused people here with my carelessness.

Comment: Thank you, @user, for participating in the discussion. With the mistake caused by me carelessness, the question really confused people who visited my question. My apology for that.

Comment: If you ever need to check an answer to a similar question, the code at the following link can be used, although it won't provide any insight (just a check of the answer):  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725052/693577

Comment: Thank you, @Joe, for your introduction to a similar question which is more complicated but more interesting at the same time. I've read that post and gained a rough understanding of the question therein. I'm not really good at math but I'm still interested in it. I wish if only I had got a mind that is imaginative as well logical enough to grasp problems like my question and that question. It's really fun when we can form a clear picture of a very complex matter and express it in simple mathematical language. IMHO, math really is God's wonder tool to create laws that govern the whole universe.

Comment: I have no doubt from how articulate you are that you possess the mental faculties necessary to understand similar problems, and you’ve definitely expressed sufficient passion for the subject. It just takes putting in the time studying, and of course access to resources. I also desire to be better at math, but other commitments limit my study time  :(        After I retire, I hope to have more time for math!

Comment: Many thanks, @Joe, for your compliment and encouragement. I'll surely try my best. I'm really interested in computer programming which heavily relies on maths indeed. Just like you, learning programming and math is what I try to do well in my spare time after work and family life. It's not easy for sure, but that makes it more enjoyable when I have time for it. Good luck to you, too, pal. Hope you'll enjoy your time learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer should be 96 (of course, without duplicate arrangements). There are many ways to solve this problem.

Method 1. Start with arrangements of _ I _ N _ I _ U _ and place 3 Ms in 3 of 5 places. Then subtract arrangements where 2 I's are together

$$= \frac{4!}{2!} . \binom{5}{3} - 3!.\binom{4}{3}$$

Method 2. Start with arrangements of _ N _ U _ and place 2 I's in 2 of 3 places. This results in 4 letters and 5 adjacent places. Then place 3 M's in 3 of 5 places. Then add arrangements where I's are together. Place one M between two I's and 2 M's in 2 of  resulting 4 places.

$$= 2!.\binom{3}{2}.\binom{5}{3} + 2!.\binom{3}{1}.\binom{4}{2}$$

Method 3. Start with arrangements of _ N _ U _ and place 3 M's in 3 places. This results in 5 letters and 6 adjacent places. Then place 2 I's in 2 of 6 places. Then add arrangements where 2 M's are together. Place the other M in 1 of 2 remaining places. Then place one I between two M's and other I in resulting 5 places. The last step will be to add arrangement where all M's are together. Place 2 I's between 3 M's to separate them.

$$= 2!.\binom{3}{3}.\binom{6}{2} + 2!.\binom{3}{1}.\binom{2}{1}.\binom{5}{1} + 2!.\binom{3}{1}$$

Comment: According to the title (but not the question text), the I's don't have to be separated. I have asked the OP for clarification.

Comment: I agree. I went by the body of the question - Find the number of arrangements of all 7 letters of the word "MINIMUM" in which the letters are separated. If only letter M's have to be separated then the answer will be 120 (method 1, without 24 deduction).

Comment: Thank you, @MathLover. The body of the question has been revised so that the condition now is "the letters M are separated". So, the result is 120 as suggested by you and other people who came to my help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 720.

This comes from first seating all letters apart from the 3 M's in 4!/2! ways (4 letters, double I's).
After this, we must then PERMUTE (Pick) 3 places out of the 5 'in-betweens' of the 4 letters we placed earlier (I, I, U, N).

Hence, we have:
4!/2! multiplied by 5P3

Visual Representation:
_**I_I_U_N** _